# JavaScript ActiveXObject - How to run win32 apps and wait for their termination before next step?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, command-prompt, activexobject

Normal behavior of "start /wait" in the command line:
start /wait services.msc /computer=localhost & <"additional commands when GUI is closed">

I want to use above command in HTML->JavaScript->ActiveXObject->Windows Shell.
For that purpose in Windows Shell I have to invoke CMD first, otherwise it wont work.

Problem: The additional commands separated by "&" are executed immediately after GUI window loads. Why the /wait switch does not waits the termination the GUI process?

Example:

```
function Example() {
  var command = "cmd /c start /wait <GUI_process.exe> <Parameters> & <execute 
  some cleanup commands if GUI is closed>;

  var WinShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  WinShell.Run(command, 1, false);
}
```

Looks like there is no way to overcome the bug in start /wait command. Microsoft abandoned the support of predefined commands a long time ago.

Workaround: PowerShell

Only the Cmdlet command "Start-Process -Wait" works as expected for invoked GUI.

The struggle: On some workstations the PowerShell is disabled by GPO so I can't use it.

The real question: Is there a way to make "start /wait" work properly in above example?

Comment: Have you considered `&&`

Comment: && - works like single &. I found out that problem comes from parameters. If I use at least one parameter the wait switch does not work. Example: mmc.exe services.msc && taskmgr.exe. If services.msc is skipped the wait switch works fine.

Comment: Don't use `start` command. Try this: `cmd /C calc.exe | pause & echo Show this after calc.exe is closed`

Answer (score 0):

[See story below]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script>
            function fun(){
                var fs = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
                var tmp = fs.GetSpecialFolder(2);
                var cs = fs.OpenTextFile(tmp+"\\test.cs", 8, true);
                cs.WriteLine("using System.Diagnostics;class test{public static void Main(string[] args){");
                cs.WriteLine("ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(\"cmd.exe\", \"/c %TMP%\\\\test.bat\");");
                cs.WriteLine("Process.Start(processInfo).Close();}}");
                cs.Close();
                var bat=fs.OpenTextFile(tmp+"\\test.bat", 8, true);
                bat.WriteLine("echo ASDF");
                bat.WriteLine("services.msc");
                bat.WriteLine("echo ZXCV");
                bat.WriteLine("pause");
                bat.Close();
                var command="cmd /c \\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5\\csc.exe /out:%tmp%\\test.exe %tmp%\\test.cs & %tmp%\\test.exe & pause";
                var WinShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                WinShell.Run(command, 1, false);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="fun()">Butt</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code above creates `test.cs` and `test.bat` into the user's temp folder, then compiles the C# code with the 32-bit .NET v3.5 compiler, present in all Windows 7 installations (including 64-bit), and then the resulting `test.exe` launches `test.bat`, which causes execution properly wait for the MMC snap-in (`services.msc` here) to finish.

---

**Story**

- The issue is not about GUI/non-GUI: various applications, like the Calculator or the Task Manager do suspend execution of the command-chain until they return:
  `var command="cmd /c echo ZXCV & calc & echo ASDF & pause";`
  `var command="cmd /c echo ZXCV & taskmgr & echo ASDF & pause";`
- It is not directly related to privilege elevation either:
  `var command="cmd /c echo ZXCV & diskpart & echo ASDF & pause";` - "normally" it will ask for admin privileges and run the tool in a separate window. When started from "admin-IE" (IE started with right-click, Run as Administrator), it has both echoes and diskpart in the same window
  `var command="cmd /c echo ZXCV & fsutil & echo ASDF & pause";` - fsutil does not ask for elevation, "normal" execution results in an error message, "admin-IE" results in a list of supported arguments
- It is not related to elevated GUI executables either, Registry Editor works fine:
  `var command="cmd /c echo ZXCV & regedit & echo ASDF & pause";`
- It seems to be related to MMC snap-ins, but for example Resource Monitor is affected too (while it has its own executable, `perfmon.exe`, it really resembles MMC, especially when started without any arguments):
  `var command="cmd /c echo ZXCV & perfmon & echo ASDF & pause";`
  `var command="cmd /c echo ZXCV & services.msc & echo ASDF & pause";`
  `var command="cmd /c echo ZXCV & start /wait perfmon & echo ASDF & pause";`
  `var command="cmd /c echo ZXCV & start /wait services.msc & echo ASDF & pause";`
  Here nothing matters, direct execution, `start /wait`, nor "admin-IE".
- You mentioned that this kind of chaining works from the command line or from a batch file. So the next idea was to 'drop' a batch file and run it. As I was lazy, I just created the file myself:
  `echo ZXCV`
  `services.msc`
  `echo ASDF`
  `pause`
  This batch file, when run directly, waits for MMC to exit (even without `start /wait`). However when executed via IE+ActiveX (including "admin-IE"),
  `var command="%USERPROFILE%\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CmdTest\\test.bat";`
  it does not wait, just runs until the `pause` like all the other attempts above. (For completeness it was also tested with `cmd /c` and `start /wait`, but their presence did not matter)

My next idea would be to drop some tiny .NET code, like

```
using System.Diagnostics;
class test{
  public static void Main(string[] args){
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c %USERPROFILE%\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CmdTest\\test.bat");
    Process.Start(processInfo).Close();
  }
}
```

... and then it worked.

Of course all kind of warnings apply here about the year being 2018, IE being this and that, how ActiveX mass murders baby seals and fluffy kittens, et cetera.
Also, if non-Win7 OS-es are to be supported, the code could look around what .NET frameworks are present and use an existing one. Plus as the hardcoded `test.xy`-s may hurt someone's eyes, [`GetTempName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0azsy9b(v=vs.84).aspx) could be used to create non-conflicting names (or a single one, reused with different extensions, just like `test`), though the extensions have to be .cs, .exe and .bat (perhaps the .cs can be something else, I have not tried).